# Flutter: prevent refreshing website inside a webview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout

I am using webview flutter inside a viewpager:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductNeedConfigModel items = result["Data"] as ProductNeedConfigModel;
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          controller: PageController(
            initialPage: 0,
            viewportFraction: 1.0,
            keepPage: true,
          ),
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (contex, index) =>
              ConfigWebViewScreen(result)),
    );
  }
```

and my webView page:

```
class ConfigWebViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  ConfigWebViewScreen(this._result);
  final dynamic _result;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var partyId = _result["Data"].data[0].partyId;
    var configIds = _result["configIds"][0];
    String url =
        "${_result["Data"].data[0].url}/?accountId=$partyId&conversationId=$configIds";

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: url.toString(),
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onPageFinished: (val) {
            print('The result is $val');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is every time that i swap or change the page, that site displayed on webview is refreshed ??How can i prevent this refreshing ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No Unfortunately so I changed implementation completely.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found solution:

First of all you need to create list of WebviewScreenState-s. You will use it when onBack
was pressed:

```
 final List _screenStates = [
    GlobalKey<WebviewScreenState>(),
    GlobalKey<WebviewScreenState>(),
    GlobalKey<WebviewScreenState>(),
    GlobalKey<WebviewScreenState>(),
  ];
```

Then you need to create layout with PageView and BottomAppBar:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        GlobalKey<WebviewScreenState> key = _screenStates[_pressedPosition];
        bool handle = !await key.currentState.canGoBack();
        return handle;
        // if (handle) {
        //   return await _showExitDialog(context);
        // } else {
        //   return handle;
        // }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _pageController,
          children: [
            WebviewScreen(
              initialUrl: 'https://someurl.com',
              key: _screenStates[0],
            ),
            WebviewScreen(
              initialUrl: 'https://someurl.com',
              key: _screenStates[1],
            ),
            WebviewScreen(
                initialUrl: 'https://someurl.com',
                key: _screenStates[2]),
            WebviewScreen(
                initialUrl: 'https://someurl.com',
                key: _screenStates[3]),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            height: BottomAppBarHeight,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                _createMenuItem('Список вакансий', 0, Icons.search),
                Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
                _createMenuItem('Список соискателей', 1, Icons.person),
                
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: IconButton(
                    tooltip: 'Список соискателей',
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    splashRadius: 28.0,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person_search,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: (_pressedPosition == 1)
                          ? PrimaryColor
                          : DarkerGreyColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => _onMenuTapped(1),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          notchMargin: 7.0,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
_onMenuTapped(int position) {
    setState(() {
      _pressedPosition = position;
      _pageController.animateToPage(position,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }
.....
```

Pay attention for WebviewScreen which is statefull widget with webview:

```
class WebviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialUrl;
  final GlobalKey key;

  WebviewScreen({this.key, @required this.initialUrl});

  @override
  WebviewScreenState createState() => WebviewScreenState();
}

class WebviewScreenState extends State<WebviewScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  WebViewController _controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            WebView(
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
              initialUrl: widget.initialUrl,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(PaddingLarge),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: DarkerGreyColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(BorderRadiusMedium),
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left,
                          size: 24.0, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
                      onPressed: () => canGoBack()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(PaddingLarge),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: DarkerGreyColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(BorderRadiusMedium),
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.refresh,
                          size: 24.0, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
                      onPressed: () => _refresh()),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<bool> canGoBack() async {
    if (_controller == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      await _controller.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  _refresh() {
    if (_controller != null) {
      _controller.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin is the key for keeping webview alive without recreating. This method will handle refreshing:

```
@override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```